# Multiple IP address on an unmanaged switch

Tags: switch, router, isp

Sorry if this question have been already asked. My ISP is providing multiple public IP's on an interface. Can I use an unmanaged switch to conect to ISP's interface and then connect this switch to multiple routers (Draytek/TP link) to make use of these IP's?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most often. It depends on how exactly your ISP connects your IP addresses into their network.

Usually, you're given a subnet where one IP address is used by their router - e.g. 192.0.2.32/28 with the router on .33, and .34 through .46 for you to use. You can then connect a firewall and map those addresses into your network, but you can just as well connect a (managed or unmanaged) switch and behind that individual devices with one address each. This is the most common method for small, ISP-owned ranges.

Another variant is to provide you with a point-to-point address (/31 or /30 prefix) and *another* subnet that needs to routed over that p2p address. That way, a router on your side is always required. Since there's no NAT, you could also use a layer-3 switch with an appropriate routing setup. This setup is common if you own an IP range yourself and have it routed through your ISP (with or without BGP).